# Removing single construct results in incorrect execution

Tags: c++, openmp

This code works as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <omp.h>

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970024/jacobi-relaxation-in-mpi
#define max(a, b) (a)>(b)?(a):(b)

const int m = 2001;
const int n = 1500;
const int p = 4;

double v[m + 2][m + 2];
double x[m + 2];
double y[m + 2];
double _new[m + 2][m + 2];
double maxdiffA[p + 1];
int icol, jrow;

int main() {
    omp_set_num_threads(p);

    double h = 1.0 / (n + 1);

    double start = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel for private(icol) shared(x, y, v, _new)
    for (icol = 0; icol <= n + 1; ++icol) {
        x[icol] = y[icol] = icol * h;

        _new[icol][0] = v[icol][0] = 6 - 2 * x[icol];

        _new[n + 1][icol] = v[n + 1][icol] = 4 - 2 * y[icol];

        _new[icol][n + 1] = v[icol][n + 1] = 3 - x[icol];

        _new[0][icol] = v[0][icol] = 6 - 3 * y[icol];
    }

    const double eps = 0.01;


    #pragma omp parallel private(icol, jrow) shared(_new, v, maxdiffA)
    {
        while (true) { //for [iters=1 to maxiters by 2]
            #pragma omp single
            for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) maxdiffA[i] = 0;
            #pragma omp for
            for (icol = 1; icol <= n; icol++)
                for (jrow = 1; jrow <= n; jrow++)
                    _new[icol][jrow] =
                            (v[icol - 1][jrow] + v[icol + 1][jrow] + v[icol][jrow - 1] + v[icol][jrow + 1]) / 4;
            #pragma omp for
            for (icol = 1; icol <= n; icol++)
                for (jrow = 1; jrow <= n; jrow++)
                    v[icol][jrow] = (_new[icol - 1][jrow] + _new[icol + 1][jrow] + _new[icol][jrow - 1] +
                                     _new[icol][jrow + 1]) / 4;

            #pragma omp for
            for (icol = 1; icol <= n; icol++)
                for (jrow = 1; jrow <= n; jrow++)
                    maxdiffA[omp_get_thread_num()] = max(maxdiffA[omp_get_thread_num()],
                                                         fabs(_new[icol][jrow] - v[icol][jrow]));

            #pragma omp barrier

            double maxdiff = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k < p; ++k) {
                maxdiff = max(maxdiff, maxdiffA[k]);
            }


            if (maxdiff < eps)
                break;
            #pragma omp single
            std::cout << maxdiff << std::endl;
        }
    }
    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("start = %.16lf\nend = %.16lf\ndiff = %.16lf\n", start, end, end - start);

    return 0;
}
```

It outputs

```
1.12454
<106 iterations here>
0.0100436
start = 1527366091.3069999217987061
end = 1527366110.8169999122619629
diff = 19.5099999904632568
```

But if I remove

```
#pragma omp single
std::cout << maxdiff << std::endl;
```

the program either seems to run infinitely long or I get

```
start = 1527368219.8810000419616699
end = 1527368220.5710000991821289
diff = 0.6900000572204590
```

Why is that so?

Comment: Please focus on **one question per question**. I have addressed your primary question regarding correctness in the absence of the `omp single`. For further issues please open up follow up question. Be sure to read [ask] and [mcve]. Any performance-related question must include the specific measurement setup and results! For the debugging part describe more clearly what and how you tried it and what the exact observation is.

Comment: Besides observing suggestions already posed, if you don't see the obvious serial dependencies in certain loops, you should try applying parallelism incrementally so as to see which loops are buggy.  There isn't enough advantage in putting multiple omp for inside a single parallel to justify trying it all in one shot, particularly if you don't use a race detection utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite `maxdiffA` at the beginning of the while loop - this must be isolated from reading `maxdiffA` at the end to check the condition. Otherwise one thread may already reset the values before another thread gets the chance to read them. The `omp single` construct at the end of the loop acts as isolation due to the implicit barrier at the end of `omp single` constructs. However there is no barrier at the beginning of `omp single` constructs. Also *"a whole lot of code"* is not a safe barrier. So if there is no valid implicit barrier, you must protect entry to the reset code with an `#pragma omp barrier`.

That said I highly recommend to restructure the code to have a shared exit condition that is also computed in a `single` construct. This makes it more clear that all threads process exit the `while`-loop at the same time. Otherwise the code is ill-defined.

Comment: I'd love to ask more questions but freaking SO says "It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon! " Maybe I'll do it using another account... But I don't understand the "this must be isolated from reading maxdiffA at the end" Isn't it isolated by whole lot of intermediate code? And why if `omp single` acts as isolation, it doen't act so at the beginning (isn't enough at the beginning)?

Comment: I would not recommend circumventing throttling mechanisms in any way. I updated the answer to explain in more detail the data race.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50551415/why-omp-version-is-slower-than-serial Here's the followup question. Could you help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555707/debugging-using-openmp Here's about the fact that some things are always <optimised out> I can't find a way to fix it